# Is there a way of restoring a MySQL database on a time schedule

Tags: php, mysql, ftp, backup, restore

I've been creating scheduled MySQL backups and then sending them via FTP to another test server using PHP. I need to know if there is a program that I can run to restore the files on my other server but using a scheduled restore?

Thanks

Comment: Look into CRON jobs: http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html

Comment: Have done, still need a script to run with the CRON job

Comment: What format are your backups in?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a CRON job which launches a shell code.

For instance if you want to inject a backup database:

```
mysql -u user -ppassword database < yourbackupfile.sql
```

Now if you want to create a dump:

```
mysqldump -u user -ppassword database > yourbackupfile.sql
```

Comment: The name of the backup file will always change as the date is built into the name so i'm not sure if this will work

Comment: Scan the directory you are copying them to and select the one with that was created last?

Comment: If u need dynamic filename set backup_`date '+%m-%d-%y_%H:%M:%S'`.sql